# Enviar um comando de Enter usando o SendMessage Ou PostMessage DLL

Tags: c#

Estou tentando enviar um comando enter usando c #, eu posso escrever em outro processo usando esta dll, mas quando estou tentando enviar o comando enter é escrito o seguinte "{ENTER}" ...

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern string SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Quando tento usar um PostMessage nada acontece ..

```
 public void SendMessage(string message, IntPtr WindowHandle)
 {
     foreach (char c in message)
     {
         int charValue = c;
         IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)c);
         Win32.SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
     }
 }
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não é só incluir \n na string?

Comment: Eu testei aqui e não acontece nada, nem escrever ele escreve, apenas ignora

Comment: Ainda estou tentando, alguém pode tentar me ajudar?